# Passing Model.Id in a List View using IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show a modal cofirm before delete record on rows. But I can't pass "**Model.Id**" in my View. This is my error: "Cannot assign method group to anonymous type property". Who anyone can give a solution for my problem ?

```
   @model IEnumerable<Blog.Web.Areas.AdminPanel.Models.Accounts.AccountViewModel>

   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
        // get list user in here
    // delete button
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#ConfirmModal" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="halflings-icon white trash"></i></a>
   }

   @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Account", new { id = Model.Id }, FormMethod.Post))
   {
      // show bootstrap modal confirm delete
      @Html.Partial("../PartialView/_ConfirmDeleteModal", Model)
   }
```

Comment: Because `IEnumerable` does contain the property `Id` Are you wanting to create a form (delete action) for each `AccountViewModel`?

Comment: Hi Stephen Muecke, I want to delete direct on rows.

Comment: Have a look at Tieson's answer - the form for each row needs to be created within the `foreach` loop.

Comment: thank Stephen Muecke, I have resolved my issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you intended:

```
@model IEnumerable<Blog.Web.Areas.AdminPanel.Models.Accounts.AccountViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    // get list user in here
    // delete button
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#ConfirmModal" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="halflings-icon white trash"></i></a>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Account", new { id = item.Id }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        // show bootstrap modal confirm delete
        @Html.Partial("../PartialView/_ConfirmDeleteModal", item)
    }
}
```

#### An alternative

If all you're after is a Bootstrap-themed confirm dialog, I would suggest using Bootbox instead (http://bootboxjs.com/); then your view will look something like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Blog.Web.Areas.AdminPanel.Models.Accounts.AccountViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    // get list user in here
    // delete button
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Account", new { id = item.Id }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("Id", item.Id)
        <button data-id="@item.Id" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete-item"><i class="halflings-icon white trash"></i></button>
    }
}

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/scripts/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $(document).on('click', '.delete-item', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var form = $(this).closest('form');
                bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
                    if(result === true){
                        form.trigger('submit');
                    }
                }); 
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```